Refresh page slow with Blazor and Websockets (switching protocols response 101 )
I am programming a blazor server site and I am trying to test it locally with IIS. The site loads fast and runs fast but if I refresh the page it is extremeley slow.
I don't face the same problem when running the site via Visual Studio.
Found that the problem has to do with the signalR and Websockets.
I have a hub in my code in order to send notifications.
When I remove the hub the page refreshes very fast.
From the IIS log files I see that I get a 101 response when the hub (refreshGrHub ) is persistent in code
2024-08-13 13:27:30 ::1 GET /refreshGrHub id=CfYEGcWIaUhzrewhY1kBlQ 8080 - ::1 Microsoft+SignalR/8.0+(8.0.7+2f1db20456007c9515068a35a65afdf99af70bc6;+Windows+NT;+.NET;+.NET+8.0.7) - 101 0 64 7

but if I remove the hub, then no more error 101 exist.
101 means switching protocols and in this instance it is about to change to Websockets
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/101
So why is this switching protocols so slow? And what can I do for this?
My local machine has Windows 11.

Hi vagelis, could you kindly check the signalr logging document first, and share more client/server logs for us, then we can help you investigate the issue deeper.

thanks for the reply and the kind response.
I enabled "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR": "Debug" and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections": "Debug" but where is the log file created?
I mean when running from IIS

Maybe you can running it via https, it will use kestrel server, then you can find the logs in the terminal window. For this long running/slow issue, it's better to check the client-side logs.

@JasonPan is there a possiblity that https can fix the issue?
because I changed to https and made some tests and seems ok now

Did you use app.UseHttpsRedirection(); in your project? When you start the application and use http, if you are using UseHttpsRedirection in your code, maybe it can cause the issue.

Yes I use app.UseHttpsRedirection(). I think it was default from the beginning of the project but I am not sure.
So, do I need to keep it? or not?
The issue is fixed.
If you want make a comment in order to mark this as the answer

I think you can try to comment this line and verify using http as per the original IIS Express, if the problem goes away, then I will summarize the comments. This may help community members who encounter the same problem in future. Thank you for your understanding.

@JasonPan it seems irrelevant with app.UseHttpsRedirection().
With or without app.UseHttpsRedirection() the same pehavior.
It works well with https and slow with http.
Any idea why?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
